# Benchmarking lustre filesystem

Tags: dd, benchmark, lustre

I want to benchmark the ability of a single lustre client to save in its lustre-mounted filesystem.

I am an application developer and not a storage maintainer, so i am not worried about storage write bandwidth saturation by several clients, I am worried about how much a single application server/lustre client can write at once so i can compare it to my application performance.

I found [this page with several benchmarks](https://wiki.lustre.org/Category:Benchmarking), but all seem to be interested in configuring several clients at once instead of using just one client. Is any of these more interesting for what i am looking?

Alternatively, i have a naive script which uses dd to benchmark filesystems in different block sizes and counts. Can I trust the results that I obtained by running this dd script in my lustre client? If not, why? I know i am limited by my network bandwidth, but i am interested in understanding how it limits my performance too.

Comment: `bonnie++` is a free disk/filesystem benchmarking tool. It might already be installed on your system Try `man bonnie++`, check with your packaging system or sysadmin,  or see https://doc.coker.com.au/projects/bonnie/

Comment: I installed it and tested. The usage is nice. I am not fond of the way it presents data, but its nice enough. Curiously, by using dd command i got a result far below what i expected from my storage:  41.5 MB/s compared to 407 MB/s in local disk saving.

Answer (score 0):

Lustre clients with good networking and storage can get about 1-2GB/s with a single threaded write due to Linux page cache performance limits.  Multiple threads writing to multiple separate files on a single client can get more performance, up to their network or CPU limit, up to about 10 GB/s with current Lustre releases. Work is underway to increase this up to potentially 50 GB/s on a DGX100 client with 8x 100GBit network interfaces.

What option are you using for "dd"? For example, no "bs=1MB" then "dd" will write at 512 bytes per system call, which is very inefficient, like filling your swimming pool from a tap with a  drinking glass.  Doing `O_DIRECT` with  large file writes (eg 32+ MB)  can also improve performance.

Comment: Thank you! By increasing the block size from 512K to 1MB I was able to increase the writing speed from an average of tens of MB/s to 1GB/s. I though the bs parameter had to be close to the disk block size, which I see now that is not true.

Comment: Applications should use the "optimal IO size" st_blocksize from statfs() (or statx()) to do IO to a file. For Lustre files this is 4MB (though it may be larger depending on the file layout and RPC size).  This will provide good IO performance for streaming read/write operations.